# JavaScript combine and compress plugin/solution

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, compression

I want to compress my js and css files and combine it in one file and put it into browsers cache when page first renders.

I have tried with MvcScriptManager but I have problems it does not execute the scripts.

```
<mvc:ScriptManager runat="server">
       <Scripts>
             <mvc:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" />
             <mvc:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Sample.js" EnableCrunching="true"                ResourceAssembly="SampleWeb" ResourceName="SampleWeb.Sample" ResourceTypeName="Sample" />
       </Scripts>
</mvc:ScriptManager>
```

when I use this directive (taken from MvcScriptmanager readme.pdf) it does not work although I am not sure what the attributes in second mvc:ScriptReference tag mean. ResourceAsembly would be name of the project I assume, but what is then ResourceName and especially ResourceTypeName.

I also sow very easy to use solution from telerik, but I look for some free solution.

What would fine substitute two above or do I miss somethig in use of MvcScriptManager.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) very much. It compresses the scripts before deployment, not on the fly. You can chose which JS compression method it uses. It can also do css compression, less processing, CoffeScript and T4 template execution. Good stuff, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation how to use?

Comment: Sure, on the creator's blog, like stated in the codeplex project's description: http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/18/chirpy-attains-godlike-abilities-in-version-1-0-0-4/

Answer (score 0):

There are many external compression web site available

Here are the links

- http://jscompress.com/
- http://javascriptcompressor.com/

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for runtime compressions.